# Iphone Not responding when setting webapp to homescreen

Tags: javascript, iphone

So ihave created a webapp that opens up camera/upload file on user mobile.  This has proved work on Ipad and android system. But when it comes to iphone(5c IOS 10.) it does not respond.  This is the javascript script that i am using to open the file input dialog

```
document.getElementById('input').click();
```

here is Demo

[Sample App](https://www.i-audit-jci.com/previewimageaug8) - Add to Homescreen to test, it works if i click choose file, but seems not to work on click custom button, Please let me know if this does work on your iphone when set to homescreen

Comment: You probably can't do that.

Comment: so it does work before i add to homescreen, and the ipad works either way, i am going to setup a demo in a minute

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my webapp. I have an input field (type: file) working when accessing the app through safari/chrome. But when I add that app to my homescreen, this input does not work, the click is triggered on touch, but the file dialog does not appear.

Comment: What phone  are you using